# Cannot invoke "com.example.gestion.service.TestService.saveTest(TestRapport)" because "this.testRepository" is null

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

hi I am trying to integrate Multiple_threads with my spring boot app  I create a class MyRunnable in my service
this is my class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.example.gestion.entity.Archive;
import com.example.gestion.entity.Lien;
import com.example.gestion.entity.TestRapport;
import com.example.gestion.repository.ApplicationsRepository;
import com.example.gestion.repository.ArchiveRepository;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final Lien lien;
    public static String message="";
    

    
    @Autowired
    TestService testRepository;
    
    MyRunnable(Lien url) {
        
        this.lien = url;
    }
    
    
    public static int hhttpcode(String site) throws IOException {
        try {
    URL url = new URL(site);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

    int code = connection.getResponseCode();
    return code;
        }catch (Exception e)
        {return 0;}}
    
    
    



    public static void setMessage(String message) {
        MyRunnable.message = message;
    }


    @Override
    @PostConstruct
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String msg="";
        String type=lien.getTestType();
        long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  
        java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);
        Time sqlTime = new Time(millis);
        
    /////boucle if that gives me the String msg
        



    
        
        
        /// enregistrer le test
        TestRapport rapp=new TestRapport(lien,msg,date,sqlTime);
        testRepository.saveTest(rapp);   
    
        
    
    
        
}
```

}

when I run it the boucle if is working fine but when it comes to saving the entity it give me this error:

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException:
> Cannot invoke
> "com.example.gestion.service.TestService.saveTest(com.example.gestion.entity.TestRapport)"
> because "this.testRepository" is null     at
> com.example.gestion.service.MyRunnable.run(MyRunnable.java:298)   at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

I tried to add @PostConstruct to the run() function but it didn't work
can someone help me with this problem

Answer (score 2):

**@PostConstruct** and **@Autowired** can only be used in managed beans.

To make **MyRunnable** a managed bean you can annotate it with **@Component**.

Comment: i add it and also @Service but even the app didn't start and give me :Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.gestion.entity.Lien' in your configuration.

Comment: This new error occurs because of the MyRunnable constructor which expects a Lien bean to be injected. Annotate Lien with `@Component` or `@Service`.

Comment: it gives the same error as I munching in the question

Comment: Is the TestService field in the MyRunnable class still annotated with @Autowired?

Comment: yeah i didn't change it.